# Calibrate UNITEC touchscreen

Tags: 12.10, touchscreen

I have a DMC 19 inch wide touchpanel.
The EVDEV recognizes it and it works perfectly normal despite that a 1 inch drift.
it does not take into consideration the calibration parametres I enter in 10-evdev.conf

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try Touchcal.  Touchcal is a touchscreen calibration utility.  To download the latest, click [Here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=181666&package_id=210476).  To find out how to install, a .tar.gz, see [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have a USB touch Panel